# Is there a name for the pattern of converting underlying representations to case classes?

Tags: scala

Assume a basic case class like

```
case class Natural(i: Int)
```

Which is

```
class Natural(val i: Int)
object Natural {
    def apply(i: Int): Natural = new Natural(i)
    def unapply(n: Natural): Option[Int] = Some(n.i)
}
```

but I also have

```
def xxxx(i: Int): Option[Natural] = if (i > 0) Some(Natural(i)) else None
```

that is similar to *unapply*, but with reversed parameters (like *apply*). Another example:

```
class HttpMethod(val name: String)
object HttpMethod {
    def apply(name: String): HttpMethod = new HttpMethod(name)
    def unapply(method: HttpMethod): Option[String] = Some(method.name)
    def xxxx(name: String): Option[HttpMethod] = name.toUpperCase match {
        case "GET" => Some(HttpMethod("GET"))
        case "PUT" => Some(HttpMethod("PUT"))
        ...
        case _ => None
    }
}
```

Is there any convention for the name of *xxxx* ? I thought *from*, but it could also be an overloaded *unapply*. If it were the latter you could do

```
val methodString: String = ???
methodString match {
    case m @ HttpMethod(name) => // use m...
}
```

(if it works, could fail because of overloading). But note that this isn't an extractor, but like a constructor, because it says: *if this string can be an Http method, then build it and ...* The real extractor is

```
val method: HttpMethod = ???
method match {
    case HttpMethod(name) => // and now you have extracted the string name.
}
```

Of course it'd make more sense in a GADT with sealed trait, but the question isn't about this, but about the convention for *xxxx*

Comment: Personally I like and use the name `from` for constructor methods like these. They make the code easier to read. However mapping `from` to `unapply` is a new idea to me.  It looks like a nice addition to `from` but not a replacement.